# How do you shoot a portal through an existing portal?

Tags: darksiders-2

I have got the voidwalker and it tells me that you can shoot a portal through an existing portal, yet it seems like no matter what I do I can't get this to work. I keep hitting RT and it will only close or open the first of two portals.

Is there a trick to achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried doing it from close range? I seem to remember that I was always up close when I did it.

Comment: I think the deal is that when you shoot it through, the portal you are shooting through closes.

Comment: Oh, I missed that bit somehow. Yeah, just open the portal you want to stay open last. That, or, once you've placed the portal through the first one, use... LB, I think, and close the one you just shot a portal through, then recreate whichever portal you need.

Comment: @SaintWacko cool, wanna put that in an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shoot a portal through an already open portal and have it link to the proper portal, open the portal you want to stay open last. That, or, once you've placed the portal through the first one, use... LB, I think, and close the one you just shot a portal through, then recreate whichever portal you need.